# Different validators for same model in different actions, @InitBinder and Spring Portlet MVC

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-portlet-mvc

I have one common model for a controller. Depends on performed action I have to validate model in a different way. In other words in action1 I want to have validator1 and in action2 I want to have validator2.

I used @InitBinder with @ActionMapping name. Unfortunately validation isn't performed. Probably something is wrong with name that I used inside @InitBinder.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("model")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("validator1")
    private Validator validator1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("validator2")
    private Validator validator2;

    @InitBinder("action1")
    private void initAction1(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(validator1);
    }

    @InitBinder("action2")
    private void initAction2(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(validator2);
    }

    @ActionMapping("action1")
    public void action1(@ModelAttribute("model") @Valid Model model, BindingResult result) {        
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return;
        }
    }

    @ActionMapping("action2")
    public void action2(@ModelAttribute("model") @Valid Model model, BindingResult result) {        
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return;
        }
    }

}
```